# Python/Pandas - "subtext" of integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in my dataframe with a `dtype` of `int`:

```
Time
201311040040
201311040050
201311110000
201311110010
```

From this, I'd like to make a new column, that only has the first 8 numbers represented as `int`, eg. I'd like:

```
Time          Day
201311040040  20131104
201311040050  20131104
201311110000  20131111
201311110010  20131111
```

For this, I'm using:

```
df["Day"] = (df.Time.astype(str)[0:8]).astype(int)
```

However, this gives me:

```
Time          Day
201311040040  2.013111e+11
201311040050  2.013111e+11
201311110000  NaN
201311110010  NaN
```

First of all, how does this return `NaN` values?? What is the right way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: `df["Day"] =  df['Time'].str[:8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [175]: df['Day'] = df['Time'] // 10**4

In [176]: df
Out[176]:
           Time       Day
0  201311040040  20131104
1  201311040050  20131104
2  201311110000  20131111
3  201311110010  20131111
```

Answer (score 0):

here the part `(df.Time.astype(str)[0:8])` should be revisited, a solution might be :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([201311040040,
201311040050,
201311110000,
201311110010],columns=['Time'])


df["Day"] = df.Time.astype(str).str.extract('(\d{8})',expand=False)

df



    Time    Day
0   201311040040    20131104
1   201311040050    20131104
2   201311110000    20131111
3   201311110010    20131111
```